# unit test failing for converting string list to lowercase in c#

Tags: c#, string, list, unit-testing

My unit test keeps failing in c# and I've tried a few different methods. Any help would be greatly appreciated. It's just not converting the book I add to lowercase. So the test fails

```
    private List<string> _number;

    public Book (string[] id)
    {
        //_number = idents.Select (d => d.ToLower ()).ToList ();

        _number = new List<string>(id);
        _number = _number.ConvertAll (d => d.ToLower ());
    }

    public bool Exist (string id)
    {
        return _number.Contains (id);
    }

    public void AddBook (string id)
    {
        _number.Add (id.ToLower());
    }
    _______________________________________________________________________________

    [Test ()]
    public void TestAddBook ()
    {
        Book id = new Book (new string[] {"ABC", "DEF"});
        id.AddBook ("GHI");

        Assert.AreEqual (true, id.Exist ("ghi"));
    }
```

Comment: Are you converting it to lower case in your AddIdentifier?

Comment: Not sure why this was down voted, seemed like a legitimate question.

Comment: Where is `_name` variable and `AreYou` methods declared?

Comment: @artm yeah i am. I also put the conversion method in the constructor (book).

Comment: In your test, why are you using AddIdentifier and AreYou, and not AddBook and Exist? Where are the AddIdentifier and AreYou methods?

Comment: @TheVillageIdiot corrected the code.

Comment: You probatly got downvoted because you let us lookup your error-message in our psycic crystal-balls. You know not everybody has such a cool debug-tool.

Comment: Your code compiles and the test passes as posted.  Either you have an error somewhere else that is preventing it from compiling or you have not posted exact code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't the testmethod be like that:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestAddBook ()
{
    Book id = new Book (new string[] {"ABC", "DEF"});
    id.AddBook ("GHI");

    Assert.AreEqual (true, id.Exist ("ghi"));
}
```

This is at least what my psycic crystal-ball senses.

Comment: Another nice info worth mentioning that he isn't useing the standard testing-framework as shiped

Answer (score 1):

A better way to solve this problem isn't actually converting keys to lowercase, it is to use a construct that can store the keys in a case-insensitive manner. This will save processing time and reduce programming errors.

If all you are interested in storing is the book key, then I would strongly suggest using [HashSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead.

The List's [Contains method is O(n)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) while the [Hashset's is O(1)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb356440%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). This is a significant difference if you have a lot of entries.

Here is a rewrite of the Book class using a HashSet:

```
public class Book
{
    private HashSet<string> _number;

    public Book(string[] id)
    {
        _number = new HashSet<string>(id, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
    }

    public bool Exist(string id)
    {
        return _number.Contains(id);
    }

    public void AddBook(string id)
    {
        _number.Add(id);
    }
}
```

With this revised class, you don't have to make any changes to your test method.